# In javascript how can we identify whether an object is a Hash or an Array?

Tags: javascript

The output of my JSON call can either be an Array or a Hash. How do I distinguish between these two?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

**Modern browsers support the `Array.isArray(obj)` method.**

[See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) for documentation and a polyfill.

= *original answer from 2008* =

you can use the constuctor property of your output:

```
if(output.constructor == Array){
}
else if(output.constructor == Object){
}
```

Comment: This has the potential of conflicts between different pages, since they both have different instances of the `Array` and `Object` constructor functions, that won't compare as equal. I'm not quite sure how to produce an example that demonstrates this, but I read it somewhere.

Comment: @ripper234 The problem will manifest itself in a multi `window` environment.

Comment: +1 for metioning Array.isArray. Check this link for borwser support: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.isArray

Comment: Anybody using [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/) might find [isArray](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#isArray) and [isObject](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#isObject) useful.

Comment: @akotian _.isObject returns true for both array and hash, unfortunately. You'll need additional conditional logic to iron out a solution with underscore.

Comment: Pashmam!!! for more information see [this link](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pashmam)

Answer (score 38):

Is object:

```
function isObject ( obj ) {
   return obj && (typeof obj  === "object");
}
```

Is array:

```
function isArray ( obj ) { 
  return isObject(obj) && (obj instanceof Array);
}
```

Because arrays are objects you'll want to test if a variable is an array first, and then if it is an object:

```
if (isArray(myObject)) {
   // do stuff for arrays
}
else if (isObject(myObject)) {
   // do stuff for objects
}
```

Comment: Good answer. You may want to add the every js object can be treated as a hash.

Comment: isObject(new Date())) is true, but a date is not an object/hash in the sense of this question. Of course we just apply it to JSON, but the method name is really confusing then.

Comment: `isObject` returns true for both objects and arrays so is redundant

Answer (score 12):

Did you mean "Object" instead of "Hash"?

```
>>> var a = [];
>>> var o = {};
>>> a instanceof Array
true
>>> o instanceof Array
false
```

Answer (score 7):

I made a function for determining if it's a dictionary.

```
exports.is_dictionary = function (obj) {
    if(!obj) return false;
    if(Array.isArray(obj)) return false;
    if(obj.constructor != Object) return false;
    return true;
};

// return true
test.equal(nsa_utils.is_dictionary({}), true);
test.equal(nsa_utils.is_dictionary({abc:123, def:456}), true);

// returns false
test.equal(nsa_utils.is_dictionary([]), false);
test.equal(nsa_utils.is_dictionary([123, 456]), false);
test.equal(nsa_utils.is_dictionary(null), false);
test.equal(nsa_utils.is_dictionary(NaN), false);
test.equal(nsa_utils.is_dictionary('hello'), false);
test.equal(nsa_utils.is_dictionary(0), false);
test.equal(nsa_utils.is_dictionary(123), false);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It has worked for the above cases mentioned. I have to yet come across a case where your method fails.

Comment: `if(Array.isArray(obj)) return false;` <- Isn't this redundant given that an array will not pass the next check anyway (`if(obj.constructor != Object)`)?

Comment: `assert.equal(is_dictionary(new (class MyClass {})), true);` fails - the instance of MyClass is definatelly a hash/dictionary.

Comment: Improved it a bit: ```const assert = require('assert');

const is_dictionary = function (obj) {
  if(!obj) return false;
  if(Array.isArray(obj)) return false;
  if (({}).toString.apply(obj) !== '[object Object]') return false;
  return true;
};

// returns true along your own with these values
new (class MyClass {})
Object.create({})
Object.create(null)

// returns false along with yours
new String('foo')
new Number(123)
()=> {}
function() {}
new Map
```

Answer (score 3):

A more practical and precise term than object or hash or dictionary may be **associative array**.  Object could apply to many undesirables, e.g. `typeof null === 'object'` or `[1,2,3] instanceof Object`. The following two functions work since ES3 and are mutually exclusive.

```
function is_array(z) {
    return Object(z) instanceof Array;
}

console.assert(true === is_array([]));
console.assert(true === is_array([1,2,3]));
console.assert(true === is_array(new Array));
console.assert(true === is_array(Array(1,2,3)));

console.assert(false === is_array({a:1, b:2}));
console.assert(false === is_array(42));
console.assert(false === is_array("etc"));
console.assert(false === is_array(null));
console.assert(false === is_array(undefined));
console.assert(false === is_array(true));
console.assert(false === is_array(function () {}));
```

```
function is_associative_array(z) {
    return String(z) === '[object Object]' && ! (Object(z) instanceof String);
}

console.assert(true === is_associative_array({a:1, b:2}));
console.assert(true === is_associative_array(new function Legacy_Class(){}));
console.assert(true === is_associative_array(new class ES2015_Class{}));

console.assert(false === is_associative_array(window));
console.assert(false === is_associative_array(new Date()));
console.assert(false === is_associative_array([]));
console.assert(false === is_associative_array([1,2,3]));
console.assert(false === is_associative_array(Array(1,2,3)));
console.assert(false === is_associative_array(42));
console.assert(false === is_associative_array("etc"));
console.assert(false === is_associative_array(null));
console.assert(false === is_associative_array(undefined));
console.assert(false === is_associative_array(true));
console.assert(false === is_associative_array(function () {}));
```

Notice how this will treat the **instance of a class** as an associative array. (But not the instance of a built-in class, such as Date.)

The `&&` clause above is a brutish fix for this obscure white-box test:

```
console.assert(false === is_associative_array("[object Object]"));
```

Caution: these functions will not be efficient for large or many objects.

Answer (score 2):

Check for "constructor" property on the object. It is Array - it is an array object.

```
var a = {
 'b':{length:0},
 'c':[1,2]
}

if (a.c.constructor == Array)
   for (var i = 0; i < a.c.length; i++)
      alert(a.c[i]);
else
   for (var s in a.b);
      alert(a.b[s]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For parsing json could come in handy :)

```
isArrayHashs = (attr) ->
  !!attr && attr.constructor == Array && isHash(attr[0])

isHash = (attr) ->
  !!attr && !$.isNumeric(attr) && attr.constructor == Object
```

attr[0].constructor must be:

- String
- Numeric
- Array
- Object
- Undefined