# How to check if an argument is an object (and not an array) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arguments, argument-passing

After testing out `instasnceof` I found that it will return true if the argument is an array or an object literal.

```
function test(options){
  if(options instanceof Object){alert('yes')}//this will alert for both arrays and object literals
}
test({x:11})// alerts
test([11])// alerts as well but I do not want it to
```

Is there a way to test if the argument "options" is an object literal?

P.S. I am creating a module that will allow the user to access its configuration options, and I want to test if the argument is only an **object literal** or not?

Comment: "Object literal" is just a syntax for creating objects. I assume you're trying to specifically distinguish between an Array object and a non-Array object. I'm certain this has been covered on SO.

Comment: [Distinguish between array and hash in javascript with typeof()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844981/distinguish-between-array-and-hash-in-javascript-with-typeof)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is there a way to test if the argument "options" is an object literal?

No, because it makes no sense. You can test whether it's an *object*, but how it was created (via a literal in the call to your function, via a literal elsewhere, through `new Object`, by deserializing a JSON string, ...) is not information that's maintained.

> after testing out instasnceof i found that it will return true if the argument is an array or an object literal

Correct. Arrays in JavaScript are objects (and [not really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)).

If you want to test that an object is a plain old object, you can do this:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(options) === "[object Object]") {
    // It's a plain object
}
```

But there's really no reason to do that. It's not your problem. As long as what they pass you has the properties you expect, don't try to limit the object further.

> p.s. i'm making a module that will allow the user to pass it configuration options and i want to test to make sure that the argument is only an object literal.

Why? If the user wants to use an object that hasn't been declared as a literal right there and then, why would you care? If they want to use an object that they've created via a different constructor function (e.g., rather than just a plain object), again, why would you care?

Comment: so then i should be checking for properties and if they have values or not instead of what the argument is?

Comment: @codewombat: Yes, that's it exactly. Just test for the things you want to see. (This is sometimes called "duck typing" -- e.g., does it walk like a duck, and quack like a duck? Then it's a duck.)

Comment: I wouldn't say that arrays in JavaScript are not Arrays... But they are Objects, too.

Comment: @Bergi: I didn't say they weren't Arrays, I said they weren't arrays (lower case). See the link for an explanation of why I say that.

Comment: excellent answer. i'm trying to do more advance things with javascript before delving into another language i want to make sure my "P's and Q's" (i.e. best/correct practices) are straight before proceeding and this diffidently helped with that.

Comment: don`t try to limit the object further is good but curious advice

Answer (score 2):

```
function isPlainObject(o) {
     return Object(o) === o && Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === Object.prototype;
}
```

However, you can't test wether `o` was declared as a literal or instantiated somehow else - you can just test whether it's a *plain object* without any constructor than `Object`.

Comment: Not that I personally care, but this does not work when testing a value passed across frames/windows.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However you can't test such an object anyway, can you?

Comment: Yes, [you can](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/) but it's reasonably horrific: `function isArray(o) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Array]'; }`

Comment: I know that one, but how would you code `isObject`? Oh, wait, `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(o))=== null` should work - much more horrible than the toString-trick :-)

Comment: No, just replace `Array` in the string-based version with `Object`.

Comment: No, that would be true for every non-Array- and non-Host-Object - we want *plain* objects.

Comment: `[ 42, "foo", /bar/, true, {}, [], new Date, undefined, Math, function(){}, new Error ].map(function(o){ return {}.toString.call(o) }).join(' '); -->
"[object Number] [object String] [object RegExp] [object Boolean] [object Object] [object Array] [object Date] [object Undefined] [object Math] [object Function] [object Error]"`

Comment: You forgot `new (function x(){})` -> `[object Object]` - oops.

Comment: No, in here I'm instantiating a new object from an anonymous constructor - resulting in a non "plain object"

Comment: Oh, I failed to see the `new` operator. I see, you think it's somehow important to differentiate an object whose `__proto__` is `Object.prototype` from a separate one. I'm not sure why, but I understand your argument, now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to forbid arrays, you can just do this:

```
var isObject = options instanceof Object;
var isArray = options instanceof Array;
if(isObject && !isArray)
{
    alert('yes');
}
```

Comment: check out Array.isArray() and its common shims.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use Lodash:

```
_.isPlainObject(value)
```

Here is the documentation:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isPlainObject