# Using Jquery how to distinguish whether the object value is array or just value..?

Tags: jquery, object, each

In my object loop using the `earch function` how to find the value as "just a string" - or "array" - or "object" - while loop through..?

In case if I find the value as "array" - then i suppose to re-loop the array. But how can i find the value as loop-able or returnable using jquery..?

myobject :

```
var input = {
    "DashBoard": [

    {
        "title": "DashBoard" //non-loopable
    }, {
        "widget": [{ //loop-able - it could be a object (so loop-able)
            "slide": "To do"
        }, {
            "slide": "Teamspace"
        }, {
            "slide": "Recent Activity"
        }]
    }
    ]}
```

But using the Jquery type - return always object. what is the way to find the object value to distinguish between value and array or object..?

my try:

```
$.each(input.DashBoard, function (index, item) {

    console.log(index, $.type(item)); //always return object..!

} )
```

what would be the correct way..

[fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/bJtc5/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218798/in-javascript-how-can-we-identify-whether-an-object-is-a-hash-or-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `typeof` operator to get the type of operand.

`typeof item === 'string'`   **or**  `typeof item === 'object'`

But when it encounters an array, it just returns it as an object. For that you can use `$.isArray` method of jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Checking the constructor (class)?

```
''.constructor === String
[].constructor === Array
{}.constructor === Object
```

Comment: It's useful, just adding little more to it to make a comparison using this - ''.constructor.name === 'String'. Hope this would work better now.

Comment: FF 22, Chrome 28, Opera 12.15, Node 0.8.12 -- Works ''.constructor === String perfect. I see no need to check name

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.isArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/) to test for array

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore.js 's [isArray function](http://underscorejs.org/#isArray)

It is very useful and lightweight utility library for javascript

It works for almost all browsers.

```
(function(){ return _.isArray(arguments); })();
=> false
_.isArray([1,2,3]);
=> true
```

Comment: Why the overhead of an extra library when the same method is available in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code you can use to determine if your value is a string/ object or array:
    if($.isArray(yourVariable))
    {
    // loop
    }
    else
    {
     //return
    }