# map different types of data with javascript and vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm **parsing/mapping** 2 differents types of data/objects inside **i.values**:

i can see in console:

```
(3) [1, 2, 3,__ob__: Observer] 
  0:1
  1:2
  2:3
  length:3
  __ob__: Observer {value: Array(3), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
  __proto__:Array
```

the next type of data/object is:

```
{__ob__: Observer}
  no: "I'm not"
  not_sure: "I'm not sure"
  yes: "I'm sure"
  __ob__:Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
```

this is my code to parse/map:

```
this.cstInputs.map(i => {
  i.values = i.values.map((k, v) => {
    return {
      value: v,
      label: k
    }
  });
}
```

the code are failing in the last object: **no: "I'm not"**...

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: i.values.map is not a function...
```

how can I analyze these different types of data or differentiate them to get a key pair value with other method like `map`?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object doesn't have one method=map(), so it threw up the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: i.values.map is not a function`.

For your use case, Uses [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) should be better.

like below demo:

```js
let cstInputs = [
  {'values': [1, 2, 3]},
  {'values': 
            {
              'no':'I am no', 
              'not_sure': 'I am not sure', 
              'yes': 'I am yes'
            } 
  }
]

let result = cstInputs.map( (i) => {
  return Object.entries(i.values).map( (item) => {
    return {
      value: item[0], 
      label: item[1]
    }
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will need to determine whether i.values is an array or an object (which does not have a .map() method).

There is a pretty good discussion of that here: [In javascript how can we identify whether an object is a Hash or an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218798/in-javascript-how-can-we-identify-whether-an-object-is-a-hash-or-an-array).

The accepted answer offers this code snippet:

```
if(i.values.constructor == Array){
}
else if(i.values.constructor == Object){
}
```